# Syncing files to Sharepoint from a shared folder like Dropbox/Google Drive?

Tags: sharepoint

so title: is it possible to sync files to Sharepoint from a shared folder?

Our team is periodically updating a file through a macro and the file is stored on a shared folder. Now, we would like to remove the additional step of having to have someone manually upload the file to Sharepoint and have it sync automatically a la Google Drive/Dropbox, where we designate the shared folder as the Sharepoint folder.

I know that you can have a Sharepoint folder sync to a local folder, but that is on a user-to-user basis, meaning everyone would have their own local Sharepoint folder, but that would make it problematic for us since everyone would have their own version of the file, and their might by integrity issues when two or more people update the file simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an UNC path to make a drive mapping to a Sharepoint document library:

http://servername.com/site/documentlibrary => \servername.com\site\documentlibrary

If you use SSL:

https://servername.com/site/documentlibrary => \servername.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\site\documentlibrary